# Only matching start word with PgSearch on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

My current scope `pg_search` scope looks like this

```
pg_search_scope :search_by_title, against: :original_title,
                associated_against: { movie_translations: [:title] },
                ignoring: :accents, using: { tsearch: { any_word: true, prefix: true } }
```

For now I’m only able to find movies if the start_word matches with my query

```
Movie.create(original_title: "Bohemian Rapsody")
Movie.search_by_title("bohe")
=> [Movie id 1, original_title: "Bohemian Rapsody"]
Movie.search_by_title("Rap")
=> [Movie id 1, original_title: "Bohemian Rapsody"]
```

I would like to return the movies even if the word does not start with my query but for now it's return empty

```
Movie.search_by_title("hemian")
=> []
```

Comment: Maybe a trigram with an appropriate threshold could get you close? https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#threshold

Comment: The problem with the threshold is I will have other movies I dont want because they dont really match with the query

Comment: It would be a balancing act for sure to determine exactly where you would want a returned movie and where you would not. Unfortunately there does not appear to be a full text wildcard search option. https://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/